# Object comparison method doesn't return what is expected

Tags: java

I have two simple classes, `Card` and `CardTester`. One of the methods in `Card` checks to see if two cards are equal to one another.

However, when using calling the method `matches()` in `CardTester`, it returns `false`, when it should return `true`.

```
public class Card {
  private String rank;
  private String suit;
  private int val;

  public Card(String cardrank, String cardsuit, int cardval) {
    rank = cardrank;
    suit = cardsuit;
    val = cardval
  }

  public boolean matches(Card a) {
    if (this.val == a.val && this.suit == a.suit && this.val == a.val)    {
      return true;
    } 
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Calling the method in another class:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Card c2 = new Card("king", "clubs", 10);
  Card c3 = new Card("king", "clubs", 10);

  if (c2.equals(c3)) {
    System.out.println("Cards are equal");
  } 
  else {
    System.out.println("Cards aren't equal");
  }
```

The output ends up being "Cards aren't equal" when it should be "Cards are equal".

Comment: @Eran are you sure? This is not exactly the same. He is comparing class objects not strings

Comment: @Idos OP complains that `mathces` method doesn't work as expected. `matches` compares two Strings with `==`. (`this.suit == a.suit`)

Comment: @Eran well he isn't even using that method... I think the answer given addresses the real problem here...

Comment: @Idos agreed. The problem is within the `equals()` method that he's calling with overriding it. The strings' comparing issue would have been relevant if he was actually calling `matches()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *have to* override the `equals()` method in your `Card` class and get rid of `matches()` *(note that you are not using `equals()` instead of `matches()` in your `main` method)*:

A possible implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == null)
        return false;

    // in case you tried to compare a Card with a Not-a-Card object
    if(!o instanceof Card) 
        return false;

    Card c = (Card) o;

    return rank.equals(c.rank) && suit.equals(c.suit) && val == c.val;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but overriding equals like this is a recipe for trouble... Not checking for null... And more :P

Comment: No cast checking, not overriding `getHashcode()`, you're right. But like I said, it's just a possible implementation.

Comment: Sure thing, vote up ;)